# How to remove or change a effect created by onpressing a button in react native

Tags: react-native, expo, onpress

I am using a simple icon from Ionicons and using it as a button by using onpress props. but issue is when ever I pressed setting icon ,it created a square effect as shown in below screenshot image. may I ask how can I either disable it or change the design to circle.

```
import { View, StyleSheet,Pressable } from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

//
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
   
    <View>
    <Ionicons name='settings' size={24} color={'black'} onPress={() => {console.log("bingo")}} />

</View>

  </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 
});
```

code working can be found here using expo ...

[In this link ..](https://snack.expo.dev/@martsa/shallow-indigo-apples)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Pressable` to wrap around your `IonIcon`.

```
<Pressable
  style={({ pressed }) => ({
    backgroundColor: pressed ? '#98eabf' : '#f4fcf5',
  })}
>
  {({ pressed }) => (
    <Ionicons name='settings' size={24} color={pressed ? 'red' : iconColor} />
  )}
</Pressable>
```

Learn more from official docs, [[Pressable] - https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable)

Comment: its not helping please have a look at my issue

Comment: I am not able to recreate this issue, can you clearify with android version are you running this. 
Also,
Have your tried setting backgroundColor? `backgroundColor: 'transparent'`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need wrap ionicons withing TouchableOpacity component ..

```
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setIconColor('brown')} >
  
          <Ionicons
           name='settings'
           size={24}
           color={'red}
         />


</TouchableOpacity>
```